# Why does the browser prompt for username and password with Windows Authentication for one of the apps on IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have a few apps that I need to change to Windows Authentication. I disabled Anonymous Authentication on the first app, enabled Windows Authentication and it worked immediately - I now get the Windows user credentials and the website works.

But on the second app, when I enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication, the browser started prompting for username and password.

But why? on the other website it sends the Windows user credentials automatically.

All the website use HTTPS with the same certificate and browser shows that the connection is secured.

Both apps have the same permissions on their folders in `inetpub`

Comment: Analyze the initial request to see if credentials are sent (called pre-authentication). If not send, your browser settings need to change. Your domain administrators should be your best resource to guide you on such.

Comment: thank you, where can I see the credentials? Also noticed that when I add `Domain Users` in the Security of the folder of the app - it works. But I don't want to add them. I have an MSA account for the apps. And why does the other app not need it in the list? The other app does not have `Domain Users` in the Security but it works without the prompt. Only this app does require it

Comment: If that's the way you resolved the issue (sounds like 401.3, not 401.1), then your folder permissions didn't match IIS default for `wwwroot`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights#inetpubwwwroot You shouldn't give `Domain Users` access, and just follow `wwwroot` is OK.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. if I have 3 websites, is `wwwroot` an alias for a website, or, I need to have `inetpet\wwwroot\app1`, `inetpet\wwwroot\app2` etc.

Comment: The "wwwroot" folder is not an alias for a specific website. It is the default root folder for websites hosted on IIS and usually contains the content of the default website. When hosting multiple websites on IIS, each website has its own separate folder within the "inetpub" directory.